# Div width equal to gap between two other divs

Tags: html, css

I have several divs in a container, organized in a row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#swap').click(function() {
    $('#container').find('div.blue').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('green');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
#left {
  float: left;
}
#right {
  float: right;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #9471AB;
  width: 70px;
}
.red {
  background-color: #D48A8A;
  width: 40px;
}
.green {
  background-color: #A4B995;
  width: 50px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #95AEB9;
  width: 75px;
}
.red,.green,.blue,.purple {
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="green">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="swap">Swap</button>
```

`.purple`, `.blue`, `.green` are defined widths, but not `.red`. For this example, I've given it a width.

I'd like `.red` to have a width equal to the gap between `#left` and `#right`. I could put it underneath all of them and make the width equal to container width, but I'm looking for something that's friendly with text.

I've put a button that changes all `.blue` to `.green`. `.red` should stretch its width accordingly so there's no gap. Some scenarios might have two `.green` and one `.blue` on the right, some might be three `.blue` or three `.green`., etc. It should be dynamic and not calculated against the width of other classes.

Comment: This is the kind of thing that [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is designed for.

Comment: @Marty, I don't quite follow. Applying `flex-grow` to `.red` does nothing.

Comment: Read more thoroughly - you need to add some flex related properties to the container and siblings as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flexbox` solution

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#swap').click(function() {
    $('#container').find('div.blue').each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('blue');
      $(this).addClass('green');
    });
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 0px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 10p auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#left {
  display: flex;
}
#middle {
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
}
.purple {
  background-color: #9471AB;
  width: 70px;
}
.red {
  background-color: #D48A8A;
  flex:1;
}
.green {
  background-color: #A4B995;
  width: 50px;
}
.blue {
  background-color: #95AEB9;
  width: 75px;
}
.red,.green,.blue,.purple {
  height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px black solid;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
    <div class="purple">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="middle">
    <div class="red">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="blue">
    </div>
    <div class="green">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br/>
<button id="swap">Swap</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Update**
http://jsfiddle.net/w4rxg7v3/1/

This approach lets you have dynamic widths of left and right, and middle fills in the rest.

```
<div class="middle">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <p>Content for Middle: cupiditate blanditiis dolorum natus!</p>
</div>
```

============================================================

http://jsfiddle.net/w4rxg7v3/

You can accomplish this using `float` and `calc()`.

Make 1st div float:left, right div to float:right, then make middle one float either left or right. Then set its width to `calc( 100% - sumofwidthothertwodivs)`

```
body {
         min-width: 500px;    
}
.left,.middle,.right {
    height: 80px;
}

.left {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}
.middle {
    width: calc( 100% - 400px ) ;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
.right {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the structure is rigid, ie. there's exactly 1 blue, and 1 green (as in your example). What if the left div could either be 200px or 300px depending on some scenario? I don't think `calc()` is applicable here.

Comment: **.purple, .blue, .green are defined widths** implies that total width of left and right are in fact rigid as in can be calculated. So left div wont be 200 or 300 it will be 70*3.

Comment: Yes, `.purple,.blue,.green` are defined widths, but on the left you see three `.purple`s (width 210), and the right can be two `.blue`s, one `.green` (width 200), or three `.green`s (width 150) or three `.blue`s (width 225). `#left` has a constant width, but `#right` doesn't. `.red` must be able to stretch to fill the gap when `#right`'s width changes.